# How would the use of sacrificial magic work and how much power-mass ratio would it have?

Tags: magic, medieval, science-in-society

In a world that was completely based on sacrificial magic, how would the much life/mass would the object being sacrificed give? Would sacrificing a human able to bring back another human?

Comment: Mass? What's mass got to do with it? You saying 1 skinny guy could be worth two body builders? Do I need to diet before you bring me back?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding SE. Questions relating to magic generally require a magical framework to be supplied so that they can be answered correctly. Answers on this site can provide extrapolation of given rules, and speculation on how a set of rules may apply, but designing a magic system from scratch is outside the scope of the site. Could you please provide more detail on how sacrificial magic works in your world so that more precise answers can be formulated?

Comment: As in, sacrificing a 100Kg man would yield 2,168 [thaums](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Thaum)?  How will you judge the quality of our answers?  Personally, I like relativistic magic.  thaums = mass * speed-of-panic^2

Comment: *Would sacrificing a human able to bring back another human?* You're the creator of this system and you can make whatever rules you want (as it's *magic*).  So why are you asking other people this ?

Answer (score 2):

Unless the magic is 100% efficient sacrificing one standard human isn't going to be enough recreate another from scratch, perhaps if you have the corpse of the person you're resurrecting that'll reduce the overhead somewhat, or if the person you're sacrificing is larger, younger or more powerful then they may be worth more towards the spell's cost.

If the magic is very inefficient you may need to sacrifice many people to resurrect one person.

Comment: See also [Fullmetal Alchemist](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0421357/)

Comment: Even achieving a 50% mass-energy ratio would be astounding. [Black Holes are only 42% efficient](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-O-Qdh7VvQ).